# Application.Undo throwing error and going to ExitSub

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm working on Excel Macro for multiselect in excel dropdown. Came across the following code for multiselect

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub

If Target.Column = 7 And (Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row <= 5000) Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.value = Oldvalue & " # " & Newvaluae
      Else:
        Target.value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
MsgBox "Error"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is more or less standard code for multiselect as I came to know from internet. But I'm facing some problem here.

When I'm changing the value in dropdown, following line is causing some issue  :

```
Application.Undo
```

and is sending the control to `ExitSub`which I checked by placing a MsgBox there.

Can anyone please point out why this code is not working ? I'm using MS Excel 2016, if that helps

Edit :

I noticed a mistake in the code and corrected the same, which I thought was the reason for the behavior. It did work once or twice after changing, but again, same issue is occuring.
I changed following line :

```
Target.value = Oldvalue & " # " & Newvaluae
```

to this

```
Target.value = Oldvalue & " # " & Newvalue
```

I really don't understand the reason for this behavior of the code. It'll be great if anyone can shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the error in the code. It was a really minor one. It should be :

```
Target.value = Oldvalue & " # " & Newvalue
```

instead of

```
Target.value = Oldvalue & " # " & Newvaluae
```

The last argument was spelled wrongly.

Comment: You should use Option Explicit to avoid that. Your code will always go to ExitSub and display "error", even if there is no errors, because there is no exit before. Goto is almost always avoidable, you can organize your code differently.

Comment: @VincentG : Yeah I've added Option Explicit in my code and it did point out a variable being used without declaration. But still, the issue is coming. I just don't understand why.

Comment: @ishanag24 the important bit of Vincent's comment is _Your code will always go to ExitSub and display "error", even if there is no errors, because there is no exit before._

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue where when reaching the 'Application.Undo' line of my Worksheet_Change Sub I was thrown to Exitsub.

After some searching I discovered it was due to the 'Application.Volatile True' line in another UDF I had defined in the same workbook.

Do you have something similar in your code?

Since the Application.Undo cancels the last user-interface action, I assume the sub considers as last action the UDF which recalculated when the list was changed --> see definition of volatile functions: A volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).